# How i can optimize the React-Native Code?

Tags: react-native

Currently working on React-Native where I create numerous screens, I just want to know that how can I optimize the code. Please suggest some tips. Like Number of Screens matter , how to reduce the  complexity at abstract level etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a good look at using things like useMemo for large computations that don't need to recalculate on rerenders.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Make sure you extract components properly so when on state change of a small prop not a big component needs to rerender just for one small prop.

Things like this make a big difference.